# Redundant instructions in two conditions

Tags: python, if-statement, duplicates, conditional-statements

I want to optimize the following code:

```
 for myFile in myFiles:
        file = open(filename, 'rt')
        try:
            if CLIENT == "C1":
                head = rows[:7]
                tail = rows[7:]
                for row in rows:
                    if "".join(row)!= "":
                        if not u_pass:
                            header = [ row.strip().replace(" ", "_") for row in row[3:] ]
                            u_pass = True
                        else:
                            self.usecases(row, data, index)

            elif CLIENT == 'C2':
                reader = csv.reader(file)
                firstline = next(reader)
                secondline = next(reader)
            else:
                for row in rows:
                    if "".join(row)!= "":
                        if not u_pass:
                            header = [ row.strip().replace(" ", "_") for row in row[3:] ]
                            u_pass = True
                            # Recuperation des donnees
                        else:
                            self.usecases(row, data, index)
```

The code below is repeated twice in the previous code, meaning there are some common instructions between these conditions "

```
for row in rows:

            if "".join(row)!= "":
                if not u_pass:
                    header = [ row.strip().replace(" ", "_") for row in row[3:] ]
                    u_pass = True
                else:
                    self.usecases(row, data, index)
```

Comment: [codereview.se] - But read their guidelines before posting

Comment: already did, and I'm told that it's not the right plrace either >-<

Comment: [Those comments](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154061/duplicated-instractions-in-both-canditions#comment291460_154061) didn't say that the question wasn't suitable there. Just that you need to fix the errors before posting.

Comment: In other words, if your code isn't working, this is the proper site, but you need to give details on how it is not working and ask for help in getting it to work. If it is working and you want optimization, then go to Code Review. In either case, follow the guidelines for that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should do the trick:

```
for myFile in myFiles:
    file = open(filename, 'rt')
    try:
        if CLIENT == "C2":
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            firstline = next(reader)
            secondline = next(reader)
        else:
            if CLIENT == "C1":
                head = rows[:7]
                tail = rows[7:]
            for row in rows:
                if "".join(row)!= "":
                    if not u_pass:
                        header = [ row.strip().replace(" ", "_") for row in row[3:] ]
                        u_pass = True
                    else:
                        self.usecases(row, data, index)
```

Comment: glad I could help